# BMW LVDS/HSD cable camera side connector

Tags: bmw, connector, camera, hsd-cable

Ever since I got my 2016 BMW 528i (F10), I've wanted to retrofit the surround view to it. It's both a handy feature and a very fun thing to do. But the parts I need are a lot more expensive than I would think. As I have the reverse camera, I will need 2 top view cameras, 2 side view cameras, the ECU, the center console unit with the camera button, and the wiring harnesses. I thought I could build the wires on my own as just the one small piece of wire that connects to the left mirror camera costs something starting from $40. I've been able to figure out the cables that go to the cameras. They are HSD cables. I've found the connector that connects to the ECU.But I cannot find the connector that connects to the camera.Here's the one that I haven't been able to find:

[image]

[image]

Here's the one that I've already found on aliexpress:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Do you think I can indeed build those cables?
2. If the above one is YES, then where can I find the connector that goes to the camera itself?